# Just got a server stuck in login screen!

Tags: server, login

So I just got a server back for a computer repair shop and I have always used windows for everything and I always here that ubuntu is better for servers so I told them to load it up.
Now when I got the server home it said."ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ubuntu tty2             ubuntu login"
i have looged and tried things and how do i make an account or how do i find out what the information is to login?

Comment: Ask the guy who set up your machine for the username and password he set up. And if you are not familiar with the terminal command-line-interface, you should better install a desktop environment like XFCE.

Comment: The computer repair shop should have given you the username and password.. It is also worth noting that Ubuntu server, by default anyway, does not come with a GUI (although they can be installed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During installation someone provided the system with a user name and a password after setting up the partitions. You need those. It is possible to retrieve the user name by booting up into recovery mode ([see the link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)) and checking doing a `ls /home`. The username is shown as a directory. `sudo passwd {username}` will let you set a new password. After you do `exit` it will reboot and you can use both to login.

After you use username and passsword to log in to the system you will see a prompt (`$`) where you can type commands to install services you want to use on your system.

By the way: if you want an EASIER life I would suggest installing a DESKTOP version. Ubuntu does not use a different system for server and desktop anymore; the desktop will have you suffer a bit of a performance hit but the graphical tools you can use make up for it bigtime. You can use tasksel below to install a desktop or just type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or any of the other desktops.

If you want to use the system to host a website you would install a lamp-server with:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

That will install and configure apache, mysql and php. "sudo" will ask for your password by the way.

If you want to install just MySQL so you can use a database ...

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

There are similar services for a mailserver, fileserver. If you want an overview of these services install `tasksel` with

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and type `tasksel` on command line. It will list all the available options:

```
u server    Basic Ubuntu server
u openssh-server    OpenSSH server
u dns-server    DNS server
u lamp-server   LAMP server
u mail-server   Mail server
u postgresql-server PostgreSQL database
i print-server  Print server
u samba-server  Samba file server
u tomcat-server Tomcat Java server
u cloud-image   Ubuntu Cloud Image (instance)
u virt-host Virtual Machine host
u ubuntustudio-graphics 2D/3D creation and editing suite
u ubuntustudio-audio    Audio recording and editing suite
u edubuntu-desktop-gnome    Edubuntu desktop
u kubuntu-active    Kubuntu Active
u kubuntu-desktop   Kubuntu desktop
u kubuntu-full  Kubuntu full
u ubuntustudio-font-meta    Large selection of font packages
u lubuntu-desktop   Lubuntu Desktop
u lubuntu-core  Lubuntu minimal installation
u mythbuntu-desktop Mythbuntu additional roles
u mythbuntu-frontend    Mythbuntu frontend
u mythbuntu-backend-master  Mythbuntu master backend
u mythbuntu-backend-slave   Mythbuntu slave backend
u ubuntustudio-photography  Photograph touchup and editing suite
u ubuntustudio-publishing   Publishing applications
u ubuntu-gnome-desktop  Ubuntu GNOME desktop
i ubuntu-desktop    Ubuntu desktop
i ubuntu-usb    Ubuntu desktop USB
u ubuntustudio-video    Video creation and editing suite
u xubuntu-desktop   Xubuntu desktop
u xubuntu-core  Xubuntu minimal installation
u kubuntu-active-live   Kubuntu Active Remix live CD
u kubuntu-live  Kubuntu live CD
u lubuntu-live  Lubuntu live CD
u ubuntu-gnome-live Ubuntu GNOME live CD
u ubuntustudio-live Ubuntu Studio live CD
u ubuntustudio-dvd-live Ubuntu Studio live DVD
u ubuntu-live   Ubuntu live CD
u xubuntu-live  Xubuntu live CD
u manual    Manual package selection
```